# parsing a nested Json using Angularjs ng-repeat and displaying elements to into a html table

Tags: angularjs

well to be frank, i am new to Angularjs and i am learning things as they come by. I am stuck at this thing and would appreciate a lot if someone can provide me some guidance on this.

I have a JSON reponse something like this:

```
{
    "id": "57fc5f56e40a93f2e0ae9541",
    "name": "ui-frmsintegration",
    "testCases": [
      {
        "testScenarioId": "57fc0872febe366d8c6d4f61",
        "date": "2017-01-26T11:42:58Z",
        "status": "failed",
        "testCase": "(HAT-5534) Email and SMS and null values - sms_upsert_uncheck_20150520.csv",
        "ctestCases": [
          {
            "testScenarioId": "58234352f033f0477d930cf6",
            "date": "NA",
            "status": "NA",
            "testCase": "(HAT-5534) Email and SMS and null values - sms_upsert_uncheck_20150520.csv"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "testScenarioId": "581a04a3dfa8c3dffae991f4",
        "date": "2017-01-26T11:31:08Z",
        "status": "inprogress",
        "testCase": "(HAT-5530) Malformed record with invalid escape character",
        "ctestCases": [
          {
            "testScenarioId": "58237716f033f0477d930d0a",
            "date": "NA",
            "status": "NA",
            "testCase": "(HAT-5530) Malformed record with invalid escape character"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

My requirement is to pares this nested JSON and add all the elements in single table with multiple rows. So if the above response were to be materialized into a table, the final output would look some thing like this:

57fc0872febe366d8c6d4f61        failed

58234352f033f0477d930cf6        NA

581a04a3dfa8c3dffae991f4        inprogress

58237716f033f0477d930d0a        NA

So basically, it would start with the parent Id and status and list down all the child id and status which is present under the arraylist objects "ctestCases" and then continue on to the next parent until entire response gets exhausted.

Comment: i think you need to validate that json first, then add the updated json source.

Comment: @alphapilgrim : Thanks for taking a look. But i am not sure i understood your question. Could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: the piece of json you've included is not valid, something is off. missing/extra brackets. once its valid, i/someone can give you the exact way to iterate over data.

Comment: @alphapilgrim : Got you :). I will add the corrected JSON

Comment: Here is the updated JSON Structure:

Comment: Just about any tutorial regarding use of `ng-repeat` will show you how this is done. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service nor a tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use nested ng-repeats to do what you've asked.  I used a  to hosue the first ng-repeat, then I put the second ng-repeat for the nested array in the .

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>    
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="item in data.testCases">
          <tr>
            <td>{{item.testScenarioId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.status}}<td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="item.ctestCases && item.ctestCases.length" ng-repeat-start="nItem in item.ctestCases">
            <td>{{nItem.testScenarioId}}</td>
            <td>{{nItem.status}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="nItem.dtestCases && nItem.dtestCases.length" ng-repeat="dItem in nItem.dtestCases" ng-repeat-end>
            <td>{{dItem.testScenarioId}}</td>
            <td>{{dItem.status}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Here is the working example on CodePen.  In the future I ask that you at least attempt to solve the problem. If you did attempt to solve the problem you should have posted your code so that others can help correct what you've done. 
http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/mmbvWb/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael - that really helps. I was wondering that if i had to dig down one more level, (like ctestCases would now have array of say dtestCases), then i need to add the following:

Comment: <tr ng-if="item.ctestCases.dtestCases && item.ctestCases.dtestCases" ng-repeat="cItem in item.ctestCases">
            <td>{{cItem.testScenarioId}}</td>
            <td>{{cItem.status}}</td>
          </tr>

Comment: To add another you will need to use ng-repeat-start on the first <tr> with the repeat.  Then you can add an additional <tr> with the similar code to the nested row in the previous example.  In this new <tr> you will need to add ng-repeat-end.  I updated the codepen to add an additional nested list.

Comment: Awesome! That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Michael - you saved my day!